# How to put an application with MongoDb Atlas on a git?

Tags: mongodb, git, github, mongodb-atlas

I want to put an application on the MERN stack on the github for my portfolio. My database is on MongoDB Atlas.

To connect to it, I use `mongoose.connect ('mongodb + srv: // USERNAME: PASSWORD@cluster0.vtexx.mongodb.net/blog? RetryWrites = true & w = majority', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});`

What should I do with this line so that the person who cloned my repository can evaluate my application, but without knowing my username and password for MongoDB Atlas?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `.env` file that contains environment variables like the Mongo username and password. That file should be added to your `.gitignore` file so that it is not checked into source control.

From this example: https://alligator.io/react/mern-stack-intro/

> Your .env file should contain your environment variables:

```
PORT=3000
DEBUG=true
API_URL=http://localhost:3000
CORS_ORIGINS=http://localhost:8080
APP_SECRET='something secret'
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost/mern-starter
```

You'd reference these variables in your JS code like so:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

You can then check in a file called `.env.example` that contains the base variable names and some sample values. Users that clone your repo can copy/rename the file to `.env` and enter their own credentials to run it themselves.

Comment: But still, if they download my project, they will not be able to connect to the database without .env

Comment: This is why you check in an `.env.example` file that contains the variables with no values. You'll also need to add a `README.md` file with instructions.